# Some Category pages taking exactly 10 seconds to load

Tags: magento-1.7, category, performance

Magento V. 1.7x

On the menu bar there are multiple categories like boats, cars, trucks etc.

Some of these categories, whatever is in Cars & Trucks are taking exactly 10 seconds to load. I am not sure why these are taking 10 seconds before they even show anything on the page.

Here is the page taking a long time to load:
https://www.sealskincovers.com/index.php/landing/allcarcovers.html

This is another category page that loads fine:
https://www.sealskincovers.com/index.php/landing/allboatcovers.html

I have performed all indexes to make sure its not an indexing issue.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: we use NewRelic and running a trace shows the following: http://www.screencast.com/t/LmVtcqBO

Comment: this screenshot shows the time on the trace details: http://www.screencast.com/t/P73NGpgHh4d

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use gtmetrix.com and googlepagespeed to analyze and tweak some point that cause your website slow.

as I see on the checking result :

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.sealskincovers.com/lBIEathf

and

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sealskincovers.com

there is some points that you can do to optimize your website performance.

if it does not enough, maybe you could check the database too. enable the `slow_query_log` to see what query that most of take your server resource once you have found it you can do optimize database to decrease load time your website. you can follow this tutorial to activate `slow_query_log` :

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002888409

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I think this script you added is affecting the performance

> *Start of Woopra Code*
>      **script**
>   (function(){
>   var t,i,e,n=window,o=document,a=arguments,s="script",r=["config","track","identify","visit","push","call"],c=function(){var t,i=this;for(i._e=[],t=0;r.length>t;t++)(function(t){i[t]=function(){return i._e.push([t].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0))),i}})(r[t])};for(n._w=n._w||{},t=0;a.length>t;t++)n._w[a[t]]=n[a[t]]=n[a[t]]||new c;i=o.createElement(s),i.async=1,i.src="//static.woopra.com/js/w.js",e=o.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],e.parentNode.insertBefore(i,e)
>   })("woopra");
>       woopra.config('app', 'magento');
>       woopra.config('cookie_name', 'SSC');
>       woopra.config('domain', 'sealskincovers.com');
>       woopra.config('idle_timeout', 9000000);
>       woopra.identify('customer_group', 'NOT LOGGED IN');
>       woopra.identify('customer_cart_items', '0');
>       woopra.identify('customer_cart_total', '0');
>       woopra.identify('customer_wishlist_items', '0');
>       woopra.identify('customer_wishlist_total', '0');
>       woopra.config('ignore_query_url', false);
>       woopra.track('pv', {url: window.location.pathname+window.location.search, title: document.title});
>   **end of script**
>       *End of Woopra Code*

Try to remove that and check the performance.
By the way, i can see your dev website through production https://develop.sealskincovers.com , check the core config data if any skin url is related to dev site , or any hardcoded image of dev site is added in live site .

Try not to use dev url in production site. They can be easy hacked and may affect the production due to low security. The dev site is not ssl protected also.